# .setTitle on FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

I am using this lib to show FAB https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button, Now I am trying to .setTitle of FloatingActionButton when a user is following someone from "Follow" to "Unfollow" can someone please tell me how to achieve this?

followProfileBtn is the FloatingActionButton where I am trying to achieve this

```
    private void updateView(userItem user) {
        this.user = user;
        if (user.isMine()) {
            actionProfileArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            actionProfileArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (user.isFollowed()) {
            FloatingActionButton followProfileBtn.setTitle(getString(R.string.Follow));
        } else {
            FloatingActionButton followProfileBtn.setTitle(getString(R.string.UnFollow));
        }
```

Here is another instance where I want to achive this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.followProfileBtn:
            UsersAPI mUsersAPI = APIService.createService(UsersAPI.class, M.getToken(this));
            mUsersAPI.followToggle(userID, new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
                @Override
                public void success(ResponseModel responseModel, Response response) {
                    if (responseModel.isDone()) {
                        if (user.isFollowed()) {
                            user.setFollowed(false);
                            followProfileBtn.setText(getString(R.string.Follow));
                        } else {
                            user.setFollowed(true);
                            followProfileBtn.setText(getString(R.string.UnFollow));
                        }
                    } else {
                        M.T(ProfilePreview.this, responseModel.getMessage());
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have add this **FloatingActionButton** before **followProfileBtn.setTitle(getString(R.string.Follow));** which is totally wrong.

```
if (user.isFollowed()) {
            FloatingActionButton followProfileBtn.setTitle(getString(R.string.Follow));
        } else {
            FloatingActionButton followProfileBtn.setTitle(getString(R.string.UnFollow));
        }
```

Simply remove that and your code should work fine.

```
private void updateView(userItem user) {
        this.user = user;
        if (user.isMine()) {
            actionProfileArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            actionProfileArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (user.isFollowed()) {
            followProfileBtn.setTitle(getString(R.string.Follow));
        } else {
             followProfileBtn.setTitle(getString(R.string.UnFollow));
        }
```